# Without access to breaker box, how do I determine if outlets are on the same circuit?

Tags: electrical

I run a small crypto mine out of my apartment in NY but summer is here and it's getting hot. I've designed a mini shed for our backyard but the only issue is powering it. If I'm lucky there's a chance two outlets in the same room are on different circuits. Is there a way I can test this using a multimeter? Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would ask why you don’t have access to your circuit breakers? A detached building without a disconnecting means? 2 circuits max and it could be a MWBC no way to tell with a properly wired single circuit without taking chances. @dandavis in title no access to breakers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Home Improvement DIY. Please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I live in  multi unit building. Unfortunately my unit doesn't have access to its breaker box. I'm not even sure where it is in the building. The Idea is I'm assuming that the line is 15amps which means I can safely draw 1800watts. One of my machines draws 1600watts max and the other draws 1000watts so in order to power them safely they need to be one separate circuits. Currently, my machines are in two separate rooms to ensure that is the case.

Comment: Also my detached building is more of a 30"x20"x30" box with power

Comment: 30"x20"x30" ??? Are you that small?

Comment: It is a building code, rental code and electrical code violation for tenants not to have access to their breakers.  The only exception is if there is Facilities staff physically on-site 24x7 who can promptly reset a breaker when asked.   You need to talk to them anyway about the circuit situation, so you can just ask them which outlets are on which circuits. At the very least you have a right to know.   However, there is no legal way to run power to an outbuilding when you are a tenant.

Comment: I'm not that small but I have a device that accidentally shrunk the kids =P

Comment: Do you want to move the machines to the shed to keep _them_ cool or to keep _you_ cool? Seems to me you're going to run into thermal overload _far_ more quickly shoving all boxen running at 100% CPU on all cores in the middle of a hot, sticky NY summer in a little wooden box outside than you would if they were inside in the A/C. As your mining rigs heat up, the CPUs will throttle down and, potentially, shut themselves down. Inside, you'll pay a bit more for A/C, but the rigs will keep running...

Comment: I'll try to ask but the superintendent is very unresponsive, and seeing as my landlord would most likely have an issue with me doing this I'm trying to avoid leading them on to what I'm doing. My utilities are tied into the same meters as the common areas of the building and possibly the converted basement unit as well so "legality" isn't a big concern. Safety is however. If I can't determine that this is safe to do so I'll end up shutting the operation down until it cools down again and we can use the extra heat.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @P2000 that comment was made out of my ignorance and I apologise

Comment: @FreeMan It's to keep the apartment cool. I'm okay with sacrificing core clock speeds and small amount of hash rate to keep them within operational tolerances. The "shed" I designed includes three high velocity fans to provide airflow. I can't help how hot the ambient temp will be but I can adjust accordingly

Answer (score 3):

What you shouldn't do is short one to see if the other breaks too.

First, measure the voltage between the lives of both receptacles. Use an extension cord to get from one close to the other. If it's 240V, then you have two circuits. If it's around 0V you don't know (yet). The extension chord helps you measure between two lives of two different receptacles if the multi-meter probe is not long enough. Remember, you're measuring **live-to-live, not live-to-neutral**. The live pin of of the socket is the smaller one intended for the smaller plug blade.

Failing insight from the frist test (you got 0V in the above test), do this test: measure the voltage in one receptacle (let's call it "A"). Now you are measuring **live-to-neutral** in "A". Take note of the reading, it should be about 120V.

Then plug in a large load like a space heater, hair dryer, kettle, AC or mining rig etc... in that *same* receptacle "A", and measure the voltage. This is a bit tricky, and you can use a power bar to plug in a device and measure at the same time. Power bars are usually not for big loads as intended here, but for a short test this should be fine.

Take note of the reading and observe the voltage drop from 120V in "A". Perhaps you read 118V, corresponding to a 2V drop. The drop could be in the range 1V..3V, and depends on how far you are from the panel and how big the load is.

Then measure the voltage in the other receptacle, call it "B", which is the other one in the room and that you are hoping is on a different circuit. Keep the load running on "A". So now you are loading "A" and measuring live-to-neutral in "B"

If "B" has a similar drop, then both receptacles are on the same circuit. If the drop is notably less (perhaps even 0V), then they are on different circuits.

This trick works if the second circuit for "B" is only lightly loaded. If you can control it, switch of all other heavy loads on "B". Should that not be possible, you can perform this same in opposite order: measure and load "B", and then measure "A" and compare.

Also, it's not laziness that puts two outlets on different circuits. It's material and labour cost, plus it's a desirable feature as you now discover. You have more wattage available in one room, and if one circuit goes out you still have power.

Comment: to clarify: if the unloaded outlet exactly matches the loaded, it's downstream. If it also sags but not enough to match, it's between the load and breaker. If the unloaded doesn't change at all, it's a different circuit.

Comment: @dandavis, indeed. I'm not sure how experienced the OP is, so I tried not to get into all sorts of varieties to the same theme. Let's see what OP says.

Comment: Great! I'll give this a try. Although dandavis is right. My understanding of wiring is rudimentary

Comment: question before I attempt the first method. Why do I need an extension cord to be close to both receptacles?

Comment: @tReason you are measuring across the live pins of two separate sockets: one live from receptacle A, and one live from receptacle B. If they are practically side by side and within reach of the multi-meter probe wires then you are fine without an extension chord. Did you mean to say it's a duplex receptacle (upper/lower socket in one)?

Comment: @P2000 Okay so if im measuring the hots from receptacle A & B am I using one ground to measure both?

Comment: I just updated my answer. One probe goes in the live pin of A, and one probe goes in the live pin of B. That hot-to-hot should be 0V or 240V. There's no neutral or ground involved. Red or black probe does not matter. Set the meter to AC.

Answer (score 1):

If you check both Hots with a meter and they read 240v instead of 120v they are on seperate legs but still may be on the same breaker. This is called a mwbc multiwire branch circuit.  Your shed should have GFCI protected circuits.

Comment: Actually, hot-to-hot will be **0 volts**, not 120 if they are on the same leg

Comment: True hot to hot will be ether 0 or 240 , if 0 we could guess they are on the same bkr.